# Need to help build a control column that finds a bug with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Power BI Desktop, DAX
I need to help build a control column that finds a bug.

I have three columns: "SN" - serien nr. Data type: text, "MTH" Type data: Whole Number and "Date" Data type: Date.

Each SN has x Mth. Every Mth has just one date.
For each SN, it is true that it can not have more Mth at an earlier date.

Example:

[image]

I solved it only by counting the help tables in Query Editor, which took a lot of performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the following calculated column:

```
Control =
    VAR BugSN = Bug[SN]
    VAR BugMth = Bug[Mth]
    VAR BugDate = Bug[Date]
    RETURN CALCULATE(
               MAX(Bug[Date]),
               ALL(Bug), Bug[SN] = BugSN, Bug[Mth] = BugMth
               ) = BugDate
```

What this says is that if the date in that row is the max for that `SN` and `Mth` combination, then `TRUE` otherwise `FALSE`.

(I named the table `Bug`, but you'll need to replace that with whatever your table name is.)

Comment: @Eduard Don't forget to vote for and accept any answers that solved your problem.